# Unity sorting list based on speed value of 2 different classes

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine, sql-order-by

I am trying to make my turn system for my 2d rpg game sort who goes first based on their speed value.

I have **class** which contains *speed for my AI* and speed for p*layer controlled heroes*.
I add both heroes and enemies to same list

```
public List<GameObject> CharactersToManage = new List<GameObject>();
```

and then whoever is at slot 0 of my list goes first

```
CharactersToManage[0].transform.Find("Selector").gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

This makes it random as it will randomly add to list and then go in random order

Originally before I expanded on this code I tried using **orderbyDescending**

```
 CharactersToManage = CharactersToManage.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetComponent<HeroManager>().NewSpeed).ToList();
```

which worked as intended
however now that I need to gather values from different class that is not hero manager it ends up with errors.

I tried to fix it by doing double tests

```
CharactersToManage = CharactersToManage.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetComponent<HeroManager>().NewSpeed && x => x.GetComponent<EnemyManager>().NewSpeed).ToList();
```

but **order by** does not take in **operators** so I am bit lost as what i can possibly do to make it work as intended.
I tried to change different elements but it just keeps giving me **missing reference error** so that means I am using **orderby** in incorrect way. ( not sure though)

I cant change the structure as enemy manager handles AI whereas hero manager handles player inputs and actions.

any suggestions on a different work around or 
a way to sort it in different way?
I am pretty unfamiliar with how sorting works in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the problem?

The problem is that you are trying to cast objects to a different type than they actually are.

> How to solve it?

Simple! You need to make an interface to hold things in common between characters.

Example:

```
public interface character
{
    int NewSpeed { get; set; }
    //maybe add some other properties like
    //int Health { get; set; }
}
```

And for the hero:

```
public class HeroManager : MonoBehaviour, character
{
    int NewSpeed { get; set; }
    public HeroManager()
    {
        NewSpeed = 0; //For example
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
 CharactersToManage = CharactersToManage.OrderByDescending(x => ((character)x.GetComponent<GameObject>().NewSpeed)).ToList();
```